# dart code runs in DEBUG CONSOLE not in TERMINAL?

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, dart-pub

[image: as you can see i can enter user inputs]

**I started using dart to gain knowledge of it. It was going nice but when i reached  "getting on users input" it seemed to be frustrating. ** because my code was running in DEBUG CONSOLE, where I was not able to enter data.
I used code Runner, but that is slow and has no DEBUG option. (as you can see on top right corner of screenshot)

Now I need a solution to this problem in a way, That either should it be possible to run and debug program in IntegratedTerminal or I should be able to enter data in debug CONSOLE.

can you please help me?
the code should in integratedTerminal WHERE I CAN ENTER INPUT DATA.

THANKS IN ADVANCE?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by running your code from the terminal, and not 'Start Debuging' in VSCODE or android studio, because that will run it in debug console.

So, from your terminal, cd to your project directory, and type `dart run lib/main.dart`

Things should shift to terminal.

Answer (score 0):

### Summary

Toolbar >> File >> Preferences >> Settings >> Dart: Cli Console >> terminal

### STEP 1

Go to settings ("CTRL + ," on Windows and Linux)

### STEP 2

Then search for the setting "Dart: Cli Console".

### STEP 3

Then select "terminal".

And you should be good to go. This is what it should look like:

[image: This is what it should look like]