# Dart code is not running in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, dart, intellij-idea

[image]

When I click the green button left to `void main` which says `Run main.dart` I am presented with this error message. So, how can I then run a simple Dart code from my IDE (Android Studio)?

---

#### Note:

This question is **NOT** about running a Flutter app but the Dart code. So, please don't mark it a duplicate of questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66722007/dart-code-runs-in-debug-console-not-in-terminal).

I also don't want to run `dart main.dart` command.

Answer (score 0):

I just found that I was importing some Flutter packages in the same file, so once I removed them, I am able to run the app.